# How to add two words to bash script variable

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm trying to read two words (or more) into a variable `$ans`. It works fine if I use a single word as answer, but it fails otherwise:

```
echo "hello what is your name"
read ans
if [ $ans = "zarkon kootz" ]; then
echo "hello zarkon kootz"
elif [ $ans = "zorlac kootz" ]; then
echo "hello zorlac kootz"
else
echo "Hey $ans get off my computer"
fi
```

Any ideas on how to have more than a single word read into variable `$ans`?

Answer (score 4):

You were so close
The only thing you had to do was enclosing your variables in (double)quotes

this is how you wrote it, I just added the quotes and it works:

```
echo "hello what is your name"
read ans
if [ "$ans" = "zarkon kootz" ]; then
echo "hello zarkon kootz"
elif [ "$ans" = "zorlac kootz" ]; then
echo "hello zorlac kootz"
else
echo "Hey $ans get off my computer"
fi
```

Comment: can you explain what putting double quotes around $ans works??

Comment: The double quotes is an official way to tell the shell to treat the variable (or any group of words) as one word. This is especially very convenient when you work with filenames with embedded spaces. Therefore it is very wise to make it a habit to always quote your variables and sentences except when you really need the contents as seperate values.

Comment: The `[` is not syntax; it's just a command (an alias for `test`). As such, all its arguments undergo expansion before it is called, so if `$ans` is unquoted, the shell sees `[ zarkon kootz = "zarkon kooks" ]`. Where you expect the expansion of `$ans` to be a single argument, you now have two, which is almost never what you want.

Comment: Thank you thom and chepner. Your explanations helped alot. im Having soooo much fun writing bash scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If there is more than one word in the input, each word can be assigned to a different variable.

i.e. do

```
read lastName firstName
```

instead of

```
read ans
```

Comment: You can do that, of course. However, if you want to treat both words as a single name, you can use `read ans` and then remember to use `"$ans"` when you reference the variable.

Comment: Thank you to JoeC and to jonathan i will pratice both